# Extract table from html including images using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to download a table from html which is not in the usual td/ tr format and includes images.

The html code looks like this:

```
<div class="dynamicBottom">
<div class="dynamicLeft">
<div class="content_block details_block scroll_tabs" data-tab="TABS_DETAILS">
<div class="header_with_improve wrap">
<a href="/UpdateListing.html" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('UpdateListing', 'entry-detail-moreinfo', null, 0, '/UpdateListingRedesign')"><div class="improve_listing_btn ui_button primary small">improve this entry</div></a>
<h3 class="tabs_header">Details</h3> </div>
<div class="details_tab">
<div class="table_section">
<div class="row">
<div class="ratingSummary wrap">
<div class="histogramCommon bubbleHistogram wrap">
<div class="colTitle">
Rating
</div>
<ul class="barChart">
<li>
<div class="ratingRow wrap">
<div class="label part ">
<span class="text">Location</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap row part ">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"> <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="45 out of fifty points">
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ratingRow wrap">
<div class="label part ">
<span class="text">Service</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap row part ">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"> <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="45 out of fifty points">
</span>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I would like to get the table:
[Location 45 out of fifty points,
Service 45 out of fifty points].

The following code only prints "Location" and "Service" and does not include the rating.

```
for url in urls: 
    r=requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(delayTime)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    data17= soup.findAll('div', {'class' :'dynamicBottom'})
    for item in (data17):
        print(item.text)
```

And the code

```
data18= soup.find(attrs={'class':  'sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45'})
print(data18["alt"] if data18 else "No meta title given")
```

does not help either since it is not clear which rating it represents since it only prints out "45 out of fifty points" but it is not clear for which category. Additionally, the image tag ('sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45') varies in other tables depending on the rating.

Is there a way to extract the full table?
Or to tell Python to extract the image after a certain word, e.g. "Location"?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html = '''<div class="dynamicBottom">
<div class="dynamicLeft">
<div class="content_block details_block scroll_tabs" data-tab="TABS_DETAILS">
<div class="header_with_improve wrap">
<a href="/UpdateListing.html" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('UpdateListing', 'entry-detail-moreinfo', null, 0, '/UpdateListingRedesign')"><div class="improve_listing_btn ui_button primary small">improve this entry</div></a>
<h3 class="tabs_header">Details</h3> </div>
<div class="details_tab">
<div class="table_section">
<div class="row">
<div class="ratingSummary wrap">
<div class="histogramCommon bubbleHistogram wrap">
<div class="colTitle">
Rating
</div>
<ul class="barChart">
<li>
<div class="ratingRow wrap">
<div class="label part ">
<span class="text">Location</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap row part ">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"> <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="45 out of fifty points">
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ratingRow wrap">
<div class="label part ">
<span class="text">Service</span>
</div>
<div class="wrap row part ">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"> <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s45" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="45 out of fifty points">
</span>
</div>
</div>
</li>'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="ratingRow wrap"):
    text = div.text.strip()
    alt = div.find('img').get('alt')
    print(text, alt)
```

out:

```
Location 45 out of fifty points
Service 45 out of fifty points
```